# Google Cloud Data Loss Prevention (DLP) scanning .parquet files in GCS

Tags: google-api, google-cloud-dlp

I am new to Google Cloud DLP and I ran a POST https://dlp.googleapis.com/v2beta1/inspect/operations to scan a **`.parquet`** file within a Google Cloud Storage directory and also using **`cloudStorageOptions`** to save the **`.csv`** output.

The **`.parquet`** file is 53.93 M.

When I make the API call on the **`.parquet`** file I get :

```
"processedBytes": "102308122",
"infoTypeStats": [{
   "infoType": {
      "name": "AMERICAN_BANKERS_CUSIP_ID"
   },
   "count": "1"
}, {
   "infoType": {
      "name": "IP_ADDRESS"
   },
   "count": "17"
}, {
   "infoType": {
      "name": "US_TOLLFREE_PHONE_NUMBER"
   },
   "count": "148"
}, {
   "infoType": {
      "name": "EMAIL_ADDRESS"
   },
   "count": "30"
}, {
   "infoType": {
      "name": "US_STATE"
   },
   "count": "22"
}]
```

When I convert the **`.parquet`** file to **`.csv`** I get a 360.58 MB file. Then if I make the API call on the **`.csv`** file I get:

```
"processedBytes": "377530307",
"infoTypeStats": [{
   "infoType": {
      "name": "CREDIT_CARD_NUMBER"
   },
   "count": "56546"
}, {
   "infoType": {
      "name": "EMAIL_ADDRESS"
   },
   "count": "372527"
}, {
   "infoType": {
      "name": "NETHERLANDS_BSN_NUMBER"
   },
   "count": "5"
}, {
   "infoType": {
      "name": "US_TOLLFREE_PHONE_NUMBER"
   },
   "count": "1331321"
}, {
   "infoType": {
      "name": "AUSTRALIA_TAX_FILE_NUMBER"
   },
   "count": "52269"
}, {
   "infoType": {
      "name": "PHONE_NUMBER"
   },
   "count": "28"
}, {
   "infoType": {
      "name": "US_DRIVERS_LICENSE_NUMBER"
   },
   "count": "114"
}, {
   "infoType": {
      "name": "US_STATE"
   },
   "count": "141383"
}, {
   "infoType": {
      "name": "KOREA_RRN"
   },
   "count": "56144"
}],
```

Obviously when I scan the **`.parquet`** file not all the `infoTypes` are detected compared to running the scan on the **`.csv`** file where I verified that all `EmailAddresses` were detected.

I couldn't find any documentation on compressed files such as parquet, so I am assuming that Google Cloud DLP doesn't offer this capability.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: A little unclear what you're asking. Try to be more specific as to what you would like answered.

Comment: My question is : How do I scan .parquet file(s) in Google Cloud Storage using DLP (Data Loss Prevention)?  I provided the output when I scanned the .parquet file and then further provided the output when I scanned the same .parquet file converted to a .csv to show the inconsistencies.

Answer (score 2):

Parquet files are currently scanned as binary objects, as the system does not parse them smartly yet. In the V2 api the supported file types are listed here https://cloud.google.com/dlp/docs/reference/rpc/google.privacy.dlp.v2#filetype.